# Literal for `i1` in llvm

Tags: llvm

tell me please if there exist some literal representing true and false in `LLVM` ? I mean type `i1`.   For example for `i32` we have all possible integer literals:  `1,2,3....`.

Comment: and what is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For i1 you're naturally having 2 values: 0 and 1.